# Extended printer information in Java

Tags: java, printing

I'm trying to get some information about the printers on my system.
On Windows and Linux, with this code, only the `PrinterName` attribute is filled:

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null,null);
for( PrintService printService : printServices ) {
    log.info("Found print service: "+printService);
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterName.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterLocation.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterMakeAndModel.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterMessageFromOperator.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterMoreInfo.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterMoreInfoManufacturer.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterState.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterStateReasons.class));
    log.info(printService.getAttribute(PrinterURI.class));
}
```

After using the `toArray()` function on it...

```
log.info("Found print service: "+printService);
for( Attribute a : printService.getAttributes().toArray() ) {
    log.info("* "+a.getName()+": "+a);
}
```

...this is the result:

```
Found print service: Win32 Printer : Brother MFC-9420CN BR-Script3
* color-supported: supported
* printer-name: Brother MFC-9420CN BR-Script3
* printer-is-accepting-jobs: accepting-jobs
* queued-job-count: 0
```

**How do I get more information**, like the printer comment?

Comment: Sure you can - just use `toArray` from the super type (`AttributeSet`) and iterate the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are other `PrintServiceAttribute` implementations, but if you want to fetch more...

This is a *dirty* code only, you can also fetch unsupported values for doc flavor:

```
PrintService[] printServices =
        PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null); //get printers

for (PrintService printService : printServices) {
    System.out.println("Found print service: " + printService);

    Set<Attribute> attribSet = new LinkedHashSet<Attribute>();

    Class<? extends Attribute>[] supportedAttributeCategories = (Class<? extends Attribute>[]) printService.getSupportedAttributeCategories();

    for (Class<? extends Attribute> category : supportedAttributeCategories) {
        DocFlavor[] flavors = printService.getSupportedDocFlavors();
        for (DocFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            Object supportedAttributeValues = printService.getSupportedAttributeValues(category, flavor, printService.getAttributes());
            if (supportedAttributeValues instanceof Attribute) {
                Attribute attr = (Attribute) supportedAttributeValues;
                attribSet.add(attr);
            } else if (supportedAttributeValues != null) {
                Attribute[] attrs = (Attribute[]) supportedAttributeValues;
                for (Attribute attr : attrs) {
                    attribSet.add(attr);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (Attribute attr : attribSet) {
        System.out.println(attr.getName());

        System.out.println(printService.getDefaultAttributeValue(attr.getCategory()));
    }
}
```

**Note:** You may see repeated values, but they can be filtered.

Comment: there is an interesting spec/document - check this http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/pdf/JPS_PDF.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Below is a modular, more understandable version of the code provided in [hGx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567709/extended-printer-information-in-java/5718023#5718023):

```
public static Set<Attribute> getAttributes(PrintService printer) {
    Set<Attribute> set = new LinkedHashSet<Attribute>();

    //get the supported docflavors, categories and attributes
    Class<? extends Attribute>[] categories = (Class<? extends Attribute>[]) printer.getSupportedAttributeCategories();
    DocFlavor[] flavors = printer.getSupportedDocFlavors();
    AttributeSet attributes = printer.getAttributes();

    //get all the avaliable attributes
    for (Class<? extends Attribute> category : categories) {
        for (DocFlavor flavor : flavors) {
            //get the value
            Object value = printer.getSupportedAttributeValues(category, flavor, attributes);

            //check if it's something
            if (value != null) {
                //if it's a SINGLE attribute...
                if (value instanceof Attribute)
                    set.add((Attribute) value); //...then add it

                //if it's a SET of attributes...
                else if (value instanceof Attribute[])
                    set.addAll(Arrays.asList((Attribute[]) value)); //...then add its childs
            }
        }
    }

    return set;
}
```

This will return a `Set` with the `Attributes` discovered of the given printer.
**Note:** Duplicate values may appear. They can be filtered, however.