# Check if printer is shutdown or not using PrinterStateReason

Tags: java, printing

How to check printer is shutdown or not using class `PrinterStateReason`?

I am new in Java, want to check if default printer connected to system is on or off.  I gone through [Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/standard/PrinterStateReason.html), but not getting how I should implement it.

Is there any example?

Comment: Hope this question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567709/extended-printer-information-in-java

Comment: Check this question , i think this is duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16035739/how-to-access-the-status-of-the-printer

Comment: @Meherzad: Its listing only four properties. i need PrinterStateReason also.