# How to get PrintService description in Java?

Tags: java, printing

How to get the Printer description from a PrintService?

```java
for (PrintService p : PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null)) {
    System.out.println(printService.getAttribute(PrinterName.class));
    // System.out.println(printService.getAttribute(PrinterName.class));
}
```

The 9 year old question [Extended printer information in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5567709/extended-printer-information-in-java) has no answer yet. Only the PrinterName Attribute seems working.

Is there any way to get the printer description?

Comment: The question you referred has an "accepted answer". Are you sure it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, i tried. The description is missing.

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/harwey/cups4j seems working at the first look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for java is https://github.com/harwey/cups4j

```java
      CupsClient cupsClient = new CupsClient("127.0.0.1", 631);
         for (CupsPrinter cp : cupsClient.getPrinters()) {
            System.out.println("name" + " " + printer.getName());
            System.out.println("description" + " " + printer.getDescription());
            System.out.println("location" + " " + printer.getLocation());
            System.out.println("url" + " " + printer.getPrinterURL().toExternalForm());
            System.out.println("selected" + " " + printer.isDefault());
         }
      }
```